# Variable URLs in web scraping

Tags: php, regex, laravel, web-scraping, goutte

I am using Goutte with Guzzle + Dom Crawler to create a webscraper in Laravel. I would like to crawl urls with variable characters included.

I have a base url of http://www.example.com. Now If I went to a post1 page, I would like the scraper to have a variable of { $post } and scrape http://www.example.com/post1. However, example.com is setup so that post1 has random extra characters in the url such as http://www.example.com/21442/post1.

Is there a way to add regex to my request so I could make my request: http://www.example.com/\S*/{ $post } ?

Comment: We'll need to see some example code with what you are working on, so we know where to go.

Comment: However, you will never be able to request a URL without specifying the exact URL (`http://www.example.com/21442/post1`)...if you get contents from the base URL, you could potentially use a regex to ***figure*** out which URL you want to request.  Once again, we'll need to see examples.

Comment: take a look my tutorial using laravel 4 http://iapdesign.com/webdev/laravel-4-webdev/superb-web-scraping-tutorials-using-laravel-4/